# Getting 200 permission error while creating business manager account through facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a facebook app which has following permissions.

1. business_management
2. ads_management
3. manage_pages
4. ads_read

I am creating business manager account using user token which has permission but I am getting 200 permission error. I am using the following API call

```
    FB.api(
       '/10208598...40975/businesses',
       'POST',
       {
          "name":"manager account",
          "vertical":"ECOMMERCE",
          "primary_page":"678031702295134",
          "timezone_id":"1"
        },
        function(response) {
          // Insert your code here
        });
```

but i am getting this response

```
{
   message: "(#200) Permissions error", 
   type: "OAuthException", 
   code: 200, 
   fbtrace_id: "CVL2mV+oi6K"
}
```

please tell me what I am doing wrong. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you are most likely not scoped to that business. Try verifying that you are properly added to the business account, and that you have the appropriate permissions to create.

you can do that either in the web ui or by calling the 'graph_url/api_version/business_id/assigned_users?access_token=' to verify.

Comment: i am doing it for all users who has access to my website. So every user will get new business manager account, so i will not be able to call this api because i don't have business_id yet.